# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, typeerror, dropdown

[image]I am working in a nextjs application. I was just trying to make a dropdown.

This is my full code:

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import styles from './header.module.css'

const Header = () => {
    /* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
    const myFunction =()=>{
        document.getElementById(styles.myDropdown).classList.toggle("show");
    }

    // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        window.onclick = function (event) {
            if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
                var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }

    return (
        <div className={styles.header}>
            <div className={styles.logoLink}>
                <img src="images/itacs.png" alt="" className={styles.logo} />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.services}>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link href="/page">Docs</Link></li>
                    <li><Link href="/page">Learn</Link></li>
                    <li><Link href="/page">Projects</Link></li>
                    <li><Link href="/page">Blog</Link></li>
                    <div className={styles.dropdown}>
                        <button onClick={myFunction} className={styles.dropbtn}>Dropdown</button>
                        <div id={styles.myDropdown} className={styles.dropdownContent}>
                            <a href="/">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="/">Link 2</a>
                            <a href="/">Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <form action="" className={styles.headerForm}>
                <a href="/" className={styles.logIn}>Log In</a>
                <a href="/" className={styles.getStarted}>Get Started</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Here I have just added the classlist in the id of div!
I am trying to show the below div when the button is clicked as a dropdown menu.
I am not able to figure this out!

For anyone who is wondering what is there present in css file :

```
/* dropdown */
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  /* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
  .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
  }
  
  /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
  .dropdownContent {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  /* Links inside the dropdown */
  .dropdownContent a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }
  
  /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
  .dropdownContent a:hover {background-color: #ddd}
  
  /* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
  .show {display:block;}
```

Any Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where is `styles.dropdownContent` and `{styles.myDropdown}` set? If you use variables to set the id and className in the markup, you should probably use the same variables in your script, like document.getElementById(`${styles.myDropdown}`).classList.toggle("show");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `<div className="dropdown">` instead of `<div class="dropdown">` and `<div id={styles.myDropdown} className={styles.dropdownContent}>`

You would also avoid doing vanilla js inside a react/next app.

You would instead have a react state like this:

```js
const [dropdownToggled, toggleDropdown] = useState(false);
  
const handleClick = () => {
  toggleDropdown(!dropdownToggled);
};
```

And have a condition on whether your jsx have a className `hidden` that sets `display: none`

something like this:

```
     <div
      className={`${styles.dropdownContent} 
      ${dropdownToggled ? styles.hidden : ""}`}
     >
       <a href="/">Link 1</a>
       <a href="/">Link 2</a>
       <a href="/">Link 3</a>
     </div>
```

To make the dropdown close when the user clicks outside, you would have a div like this:

```js
<div
  className={styles.backdrop}
  onClick={() => toggleDropdown(true)}
></div>
```

that is styled like this:

```css
.backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Now since this div takes the whole screen and is positioned absolute when the user clicks anywhere on the page the onClick will fire and toggle the dropdown.

[Working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-forked-7s7hb?file=/Header.js).

Comment: You are right! I didn't see this, as the code looks like HTML, while it's not HTML but  f***ing JSX instead. Thanks for pointing out! Still it would also be good to ensure that the variable content actually matches the static strings in `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName` , apart from the code style that those vanilla JS DOM functions are probably not the "React way" to do it.

Comment: it's true that i would recommend avoiding doing vanilla js stuff inside a react/next project, you would instead the `onClick` prop on the button and use react state to know when the dropdown is or is not toggled. Updated the answer with an example how you would do it

Comment: I added my answer thank you very much @whygee for the help! It worked but took a bit of configuration!

Comment: @whygee Your method absolutely works but I have a small query. When I click on the button it opens and remains open until I click it again. Is there any way I can close the dropdown when the user clicks somewhere else?

Comment: @ITACS the simplest way that comes to my mind is to add a dummy "backdrop" div that is positioned absolute and takes the whole page width/height with a negative z-index so it's always in the background and onClick, the dropdown state gets toggled. Updated the CodeSandbox with this approach

Comment: @whygee I didn't understand that. But I tried it and it's giving me another error can you please remake the code and elaborate what to do?

Comment: updated the answer, please share the error if it persists

Answer (score 2):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import styles from './header.module.css'

const Header = () => {
    const [dropdownToggled, toggleDropdown] = useState(false);

    const handleClick = () => {
        toggleDropdown(!dropdownToggled);
        console.log("boy");
    };

    // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        window.onclick = function (event) {
            if (!event.target.matches('#dropbtn')) {
                var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName(styles.dropdownContent);
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.header}>
            <div className={styles.logoLink}>
                <img src="images/itacs.png" alt="" className={styles.logo} />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.services}>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link href="/page">Docs</Link></li>
                    <li><Link href="/page">Learn</Link></li>
                    <li><Link href="/page">Projects</Link></li>
                    <li><Link href="/page">Blog</Link></li>
                    <div className={styles.dropdown}>
                        <button onClick={handleClick} id="dropbtn" className={styles.dropbtn}>Dropdown</button>
                        <div
                            className={`${styles.dropdownContent} ${dropdownToggled ? styles.show : ""}`}
                        >
                            <a href="/">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="/">Link 2</a>
                            <a href="/">Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <form action="" className={styles.headerForm}>
                <a href="/" className={styles.logIn}>Log In</a>
                <a href="/" className={styles.getStarted}>Get Started</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Yea finally configured it out. Thanks to [whygee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17560229/whygee) and [Ingo Steinkie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5069530/ingo-steinke)

Answer (score 1):

If you use variables to set the id and className in the markup, you should probably use the same variables in your script, like

```js
document.getElementById(`${styles.myDropdown}`).classList.toggle("show");
```

[Edit] or without the unnecessary redundant template string:

```js
document.getElementById(styles.myDropdown).classList.toggle("show");
```

Assuming that `styles.myDropdown` is a string (not an object).

Otherwise your code does not ensure that the `id` and `className` will be the same.

Comment: I tried this but it is not working. It is still giving me the same error and next js is pointing the error in the closing bracket of the myFunction: line no 10. What should be done?

Comment: Which line is line 10? the closing curly braces after the document.getElementById line?

Comment: Also saw that my (quickly typed) answer uses an unnecessary template string, shorter version should be `document.getElementById(styles.myDropdown)` but that should not make any difference anyway.

Comment: What is the value and type of `styles.myDropdown` ? This should be a string.
Currently I can only guess as I don't see the content of `header.module.css` yet, but I doubt that this will return a string from a CSS file?

Comment: @IngoSteinkie I will add my error and css file too...